# Way to do editable pip installs outside of docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip

I have this structure:

```
project
└── pipable
    └── common
        └── common
        └── setup.py  # setup.py for package "common"
    └── utils
        └── utils
        └── setup.py  # setup.py for package "utils"
└── platform
    └── service_one
        └── Dockerfile
        └── requirements.txt
    └── service_two
        └── Dockerfile
        └── requirements.txt
docker-compose.yml
```

The package `common` and `utils` get pip installed in `service_one` and `service_two`, this is done from a remote pypi repository.

I want to make these packages editable, if you change in `common` then the change should be reflected in the services. I've looked at editable from git but it seems like it would create a copy within the services meaning that editing `common` outside the services won't update.

Comment: How does Docker relate to this layout?  Generally you need to re-run `docker build` and recreate your containers to see come updates; if you have a local copy of your support libraries then you also need to arrange to `COPY` those files in.  Seeing the contents of the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` would help make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the `pipable` folder as a volume for each service, after which I run `pip install -e location_of_mount_setup_file`.